# TableView with checkmarks

Tags: objective-c

I want to make a TableView with Checkmarks
similar to selecting a day at the alarmssettings.
I have found a code on the internet but it isn't working.
and I have a code from a book but I it doesn't work either.
please help me

Comment: Maybe it's your code that doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check like this and the checkmark will be highlighted for selected day. put this in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if([Day isEqualToString:selectedDay])
```

{

```
    cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
```

}

Comment: i can't figure out what Day's supposed to be and what selectedDay's supposed to be

Comment: day is nothing but the list of days you dispalyed and selected day means the day you selected, I assumed them as NSStrings.